# Why won't a pygame keyboard event take place?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make the object jump when it presses the upper keyboard. But this error keeps popping up and it doesn't work.It is a configuration in which the photos stored in the list change over time and jump when you press the upper keyboard.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/osp_git/T01/RUN/Run.py", line 123, in main
    all_sprites.update(mt)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 531, in update
    sprite.update(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/osp_git/T01/RUN/Run.py", line 58, in update
    if userInput[pygame.K_UP] and not self.SM_jump:
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

The error occurs in def update().

This update function is a function of receiving keyboard input, and jump function is a function of jumping.

This is my full code.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

SCREEN_H = 560
SCREEN_W = 1000
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_W,SCREEN_H))

BG01 = pygame.image.load("IMG/background.jpg")
BG02 = BG01.copy()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class MeltingSnowman(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    SnowMan_X = 80
    SnowMan_Y = 419
    position = (SnowMan_X, SnowMan_Y)
    JUMP_VEL = 8

    def __init__(self, position):

        SnowMan_X = 80
        SnowMan_Y = 419
        position = (SnowMan_X, SnowMan_Y)

        self.SM_jump = False
        self.walk_index = 0
        self.jump_vel = self.JUMP_VEL

        super(MeltingSnowman, self).__init__()
        size = (100, 100)

        images = [(pygame.image.load('IMG/DinoRun1.png')),
                  (pygame.image.load('IMG/DinoRun2.png')),
                  (pygame.image.load('IMG/DinoJump.png')),
                  (pygame.image.load('IMG/DinoDuck1.png')),
                  (pygame.image.load('IMG/DinoDuck2.png'))]

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(position, size)
        self.rect.x = self.SnowMan_X
        self.rect.y = self.SnowMan_Y
        self.images = [pygame.transform.scale(image, size) for image in images]

        self.index = 0
        self.image = images[self.index]

        self.animation_time = 1
        self.current_time = 0

    def update(self, userInput):
        if self.SM_jump:
            self.jump()

        if self.walk_index >= 10:
            self.walk_index = 0

        if userInput[pygame.K_UP] and not self.SM_jump:
            self.SM_jump = True
        elif userInput[pygame.K_DOWN] and not self.SM_jump:
            self.SM_jump = False
        elif not (self.SM_jump or userInput[pygame.K_DOWN]):
            self.SM_jump = False

    def jump(self):
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        if self.SM_jump:
            self.rect.y -= self.jump_vel * 4
            self.jump_vel -= 1
            MeltingSnowman.SnowMan_Y = 100

        if self.jump_vel < - 8:
            self.SM_jump = False
            self.jump_vel = self.JUMP_VEL
            MeltingSnowman.SnowMan_Y = 400


    def run(self, mt):
        self.current_time += mt

        if self.current_time >= self.animation_time:
            self.current_time = 0

            self.index += 1
            if self.index == len(self.images):
                GameOver()
                pygame.display.flip()
                pygame.time.delay(2000)
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

            self.image = self.images[min(self.index, len(self.images) - 1)]


    def draw(self, SCREEN):
        SCREEN.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

def GameOver():
    font = pygame.font.Font('NanumGothic.ttf', 30)
    GAMEOVER = font.render("GAME OVER", True, (255,255,255))
    SCREEN.blit(GAMEOVER, (400, 250))

def Background(BG, x, y):
    global SCREEN, BG01
    SCREEN.blit(BG01, (x, y))

def main():

    player = MeltingSnowman(position=(80, 419))
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(player)

    BG01_x = 0
    BG02_x = SCREEN_W

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        mt = clock.tick(100) / 1000

        all_sprites.update(mt)
        all_sprites.draw(SCREEN)
        pygame.display.update()

        BG01_x -= 4; BG02_x -= 4

        if BG01_x == -SCREEN_W:
            BG01_x = SCREEN_W
        if BG02_x == -SCREEN_W:
            BG02_x = SCREEN_W

        Background(BG01, BG01_x, 0)
        Background(BG02, BG02_x, 0)

        clock.tick(30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoke `all_sprites.update(mt)`. Therefore the actual argument of `update` is `mt`.

You have to pass the return value of [`pygame.key.get_pressed`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) to `update`:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
all_sprites.update(keys)
```

Note, if you have different *Sprite* classes with different `Update` methods, you have to put the sprites in different *Groups* and invoke `update` on each *Group* individually. Alternatively, you need to make sure that each `update` method has the same parameters, or you need to use keyword arguments.

---

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The latter delegates to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) — you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group. [...]

The former uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects — you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]